# How does QList<QString>, QList<QByteArray> in Qt6 retrieve data?

Tags: c++, qt, memory, memory-management, qt6

I have used Qt 5.15 for some months to do some basic stuff.

In Qt5, it's known that QList, and QVector are 2 different containers:

- QList will store its raw data continuously in memory (as long as the size of each element is <= sizeof(void*)); otherwise, it will store a continuous chunk of pointers pointing to the actual data in the heap.
- QVector, on the other hand, will store its data continuously in memory.

And in Qt6, QList and also QVector will be merged; meaning now QList (in Qt6) will behave exactly like QVector in (Qt5); and the original QList (Qt5) will be dropped.

It's easy to see that in Qt 5 `QList<int>` should be the same as `QVector<int>`; meanwhile, `QList<QByteArray>`, `QVector<QByteArray>`; or `QList<QString>`, `QVector<QString>` should act totally different (?) because, as I understand it, QList will store pointers (and use heap to store data), meanwhile QVector will store raw data from all elements.

So, say (I'm still talking about Qt5), I have `QVector<QString> a("")`;
Then I append, and do stuff to it to get like 100 elements from a.at(0) to a.at(99). If I want to retrieve the 50th data, I'll do a.at(49); but how can my program retrieve the data? Will it read from the beginning of the chunk, until it hits the 50th element? If it does so, then the speed to retrieve data is not O(1); and it's not *fast* at all; contradicting its description here:

https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qlist.html#details

> QList is one of Qt's generic container classes. It stores its items in adjacent memory locations and provides **fast *index-based* access**.

I know that if it were a Qt5 QList, then it should just offset the memory from the start to get the pointer to my 50th element, and read the raw data stored at the address pointed to by the 50th element pointer stored in QList; which will take O(1) time (and this is fast).

My question is, in Qt6, how can `QList<QString>` be considered to provide *fast index-based access* in this situation? Am I missing something here?

Thank you very much in advance, :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QByteArray` and `QString` themselves won't contain any data, just a pointer to a dynamically allocated array (try running `sizeof(QByteArray)` and `sizeof(QString)`, you'll get a small constant size for both).

All instances of a the same class in C++ have the same size so in an array of objects accessing an index is just a case of seeking to `element_size * index` bytes from the beginning of the array.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you so much for your help. :D

Answer (score 0):

You miss that QList in Qt6 is a complete different container than QList in Qt5. The comment about sizeof(void*) is no longer true in Qt6 since it was merged together with QVector.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, but I did not miss that part. I did explain it clearly in my post. Anyway, thank you very much, :*